# The square root of symmetric and circulant matrix is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, circulant-matrices

Let $A$ a circulant symmetric matrix. From the definition of $\sqrt{A}$ it follows that also $\sqrt{A}$ is symmetric ( and circulant ). How can I show the symmetry *without* using the concept of positive semi-definite matrices?

Comment: How are you defining $\sqrt{A}$ when you don't have positive semidefiniteness of $A$?

Comment: $\sqrt{A}$ is the matrix such that $\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}=A$. I don't want use that because I don't know the element of matrix $A$ and moreover I was thinking that one can show this observing the product raw-column of the matrices.

Comment: But there are many matrices that can square to $A$.  How are you choosing "the" $\sqrt{A}$ and why what you are defining exist in the way you claim?  For psd matrix we have a unique psd squareroot but that goes out the window when you drop it, similar to: is $\sqrt{-1}$ going to be $i$ or $-i$, or the infinitely many unit imaginary quaternions?

Comment: ... Because this is going to come up immediately when you try to define/compute $\sqrt{\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}}$.

Comment: One can construct $\sqrt{A}$ from the fact that every circulant matrix can be diagonalized by the Fourier matrix, say $F$. Then $A=F^* \Lambda F$ with $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix. So defining $\sqrt{A}= F^* diag (\sqrt{\lambda_1},...,\sqrt{\lambda_n}) F$ one has the square root of $A$.

Comment: But which square root of $\lambda_i$ if you don't have psd condition?  Again, which square root of $-1$ is *the* square-root and why the other isn't *the* square root?

Comment: I don't know, I just read the sentence "Let $A$ a circulant symmetric matrix. From the definition of $\sqrt{A}$ it follows that also $\sqrt{A}$ is symmetric". Nothing is said about the definition of $\sqrt{A}$, so I thought that was only a matter of calculation based on the shape of a circulant matrix.

Comment: note that $-I_2$ is circulant, symmetric and $B:=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies $B^2=-I_2$ so one may naively declare it to be "a square root" but $B$ is skew-symmetric, a contradiction.

Comment: @user10354138 if I find an expansion for a matrix $\sqrt{A}$ which is an expansion of symmetric matrices, can I say the $\sqrt{A}$ is symmetric?